# Debian system memory leak with slab (size-512)

Tags: linux, memory-leak

I have system running Debian 7.4 (3.2.0-4-686). It is bare system not running many processes. The only thing this system does is running two different drivers (DAHDI and divas4linux) for two ISDN cards and Asterisk 1.8.24.0.

The problem is: the machine consumes more and more memory over time.

I did some research and according to meminfo, slabinfo and slabtop, there is a constantly growing amount of size-512 slab objects that are unreclaimable:

```
MemTotal:        1025984 kB
MemFree:          648568 kB
Buffers:          145404 kB
Cached:            69952 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           142724 kB
Inactive:          88460 kB
Active(anon):      18028 kB
Inactive(anon):     3416 kB
Active(file):     124696 kB
Inactive(file):    85044 kB
Unevictable:        3092 kB
Mlocked:            3092 kB
HighTotal:        128904 kB
HighFree:          32192 kB
LowTotal:         897080 kB
LowFree:          616376 kB
SwapTotal:        310268 kB
SwapFree:         310268 kB
Dirty:                12 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         18932 kB
Mapped:            13128 kB
Shmem:              3448 kB
Slab:             129952 kB
SReclaimable:      17272 kB
SUnreclaim:       112680 kB
KernelStack:         672 kB
PageTables:          660 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      823260 kB
Committed_AS:      62972 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:       28700 kB
VmallocChunk:      93208 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        8184 kB
DirectMap2M:      903168 kB
```

How can I further investigate which process may cause this memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

The problem causing the memory leak is finally solved. The problem was in the zaphfc kernel driver for the HFC based ISDN line card. Further information (and a patch for the driver source which fixes the issue) can be found here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=721147